# Compare data from two tabs and get the result Match/Non-Match (Google spreadsheets)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

There are two tabs in the Google Spreadsheet.

I need to compare columns B from each tab and identify them as Match/Non-Match

I used Vlookup but for some reasons I does not work.

Here is the link to the file - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CoN2hwj1tmFCiiEJ2iOIkIbIBRRa39N4iOPWr_IGAp0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",,COUNTIF(Staging!B:B,B2:B)>0))
```

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",,COUNTIF(Live!B:B,B2:B)>0))
```